# How does the python sprite list work? Can i add sprite coords to the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

Hello there dear friends,
 for my python project, I made a button class -and their images, coords, actions and so on- and things working good. But I think I will add lots of buttons in the game so I decided to add them to a one pygame sprite group with their coordinates and blit automatically with a for loop.

```py
 for oge in buttonList:
    pygame.blit(oge, (x, y)
```

is there a way can I add sprites with their coords to groups or lists, to blit them all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

If each sprite has an attribute `.rect` and `.image`, then you can call [`.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

```py
buttonList.draw(surf)
```

---

Long answer:

A [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) object should have a `.rect` property of type [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) this attribute defines the position (and size) of the sprite.

In the following I assume that `buttonList` is a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group).
Each Sprite in the Group shuold have a `.rect` property which is used to draw the sprite at its location e.g.:

```py
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 

        self.image = [...]
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
```

All the sprite of the group can be drawn by on call. The parameter `surf` can be any surface, e.g. the display surface:

```py
buttonList.draw(surf)
```

Note, the [`draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) method of the `pygame.sprite.Group` draws the contained Sprites onto the Surface. The `.image` of each sprite is "blit" at the location `.rect`.

`pygame.Rect` has a lot of virtual attributes, to set its position (and size) e.g. `.center` or `.topleft`. Use them to set the position of the sprite:

```py
mysprite = MySprite()
mysprite.rect.topleft = (x, y)
```

Of course, the position `(x, y)` can be a parameter the constructor of the sprite class, too:

```py
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__() 

        self.image = [...]
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))

mysprite = MySprite(x, y)
```